# Big IP F5 Basics (show run/show conf/term len 0)

Tags: f5-big-ip

I've tried to find the basics in a Big IP manual but it seems to me the device is marketed towards GUI users only.

Meanwhile I want to write a few scripts to automate tasks on the load balancer. Namely:

1. **how do I turn off *more*** - when I issue a command I want the output to stream out without waiting for me to press a key for the next page
2. how do I show the running configuration (I think `list all` is the way to do it but cannot find it documented anywhere)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To show the running configuration you can just view bigip.conf in a text editor or pipe it to the console.

As for automating tasks, I would recommend reviewing the iControl API.  CLI commands and the configuration file formats change quite often in the F5 world but the iControl functions will still continue to work over time.

Checkout [DevCentral](https://devcentral.f5.com) and the [iControl API Reference](https://devcentral.f5.com/wiki/iControl.APIReference.ashx) for more details.  There are libraries in (at least) Java, .net, and Python to help hide the nuts and bolts and speed your development.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running something pre-v11, drop to a full shell and use the bigpipe (b for short) command(s). To see the running config, use:

b list

Answer (score 0):

In version 11, use the command "tmsh" then press [tab][tab] to see a list of available commands and objects to operate on. You can also tab complete and once you have typed out an object, press [tab][tab] again to see an update list of available commands. You can also check out the [refrence guide](https://support.f5.com/content/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/bigip-tmsh-11-4-0/_jcr_content/pdfAttach/download/file.res/bigip-tmsh-11-4-0.pdf).